# SSRS Report Printing squashed on mini-printer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, printing

Developer has `Samsung Bixolon SRP-270` printer hooked locally to their computer.

When you print from the `Report Server` to a `normal printer` the text looks fine.

When she prints to the `mini-printer` (like a `receipt printer`), it squashes the text into a very small area on the left of the receipt.

I can't see any settings anywhere that would do this.

We've thought that installing the `printer driver` onto the server might make a difference, but that isn't exactly going as planned either.

Any ideas?

EDITED: When the developer prints it out of `BIDS(Visual Studio 2005)` onto the printer it looks as it is supposed too.

EDITED: Server is `x64` and local machine is `x86`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the Body.Size for the report fits in the paper.
Can you also confirm that the Report.PageSize fits in the paper.

Don't forget to take into account the Margins (set in Report).

Finally, there should be no "Fit To Page" etc etc settings on the printer (for testing purposes).

We had a similar issue, took a bit of digging, but it turned out to be simple when we actually found it.

good luck!

Comment: yea, developer verified all of that. They are trying another printer at this point to see if it makes a difference.